# Need to Call Javascript Function on Blogger

Tags: javascript, function, blogger

A Stackoverflow member kindly provided a JavaScript code to call the use of a function immediately after the first "/a" appears on a post of a Blogger site, basically, to insert an advertisement box right under the opening picture of an post and flowing on the left side of the article.

The problem is that it only works if I insert the JavaScript code right under the end of the body and after the div tag.

If I add the JavaScript code anywhere else, including right above the end head, it doesn't work.

As is it stands, it doesn't always load the ad / box (marked with XXXXXX) on all browsers, and on the ones it does, it takes up a lot of time to load.

I've tried all sorts of things, I haven't managed to solve it. I would appreciate some help.

The code that was given to me, follows below:

```
 <div id="payload" class="left">
XXXXXXXX
</div>

<div id="target">
Content within the target.
</div>

<data:post.body/><div style='clear: both;'/> <!-- clear for photos floats -->
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function insertAfter(addition,target) {
var parent = target.parentNode;

if (parent.lastChild == target) {
    parent.appendChild(addition);  
} else {
    parent.insertBefore(addition,target.nextSibling);
}
}

var payload = document.getElementById("payload");
var target = document.getElementById("target");

var anchors = target.getElementsByTagName("a");

if (anchors.length > 0) {
insertAfter(payload,anchors[0]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: you need to use the onload handler or some framework to listen for the DOMReadyEvent like the jQuery `$(fnc)` otherwise the code will be executed before any anchor tag is actually loaded, by the way is not a bad idea to keep the code at the bottom of the page...

Comment: As it is, it works on the latest Firefox, though by slowing down the page, and it has problems with all the other browsers including IE9 and the latest Chrome where it doesn't load at all. Shouldn't the JavaScript load before the /head anyway?

Answer (score 0):

if you are allowed to use jquery you can write in the head

```
 $(function() {
     $("#payload").after($("#target").find("a").first());
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the respnose Crisim. You can use Jquery, I tried the code leaving the Javascript where it is as well as moving it above the /head, but the result is the same: it moves the box/ad above the picture and not below as I want it to. Basically, it's like it doesn't read the Javascript if I move it from its current position.

Comment: @Lars for javascript not loaded where it should i don't know, but for the styling issue maybe if i know the revelant CSS i could help

Comment: Sure, this is it (one problem is that in Blogger, the opening picture is part of the post, it is not a separate entity) 

.addin {
float:left; 
position:relative; 
padding:25px 15px 15px 0;
}

Comment: I think you should update your question specifing a little more about css, like the a tag class, the css for the a tag and the #payload etc. it's too difficult to tell what's wrong without more information.